# UI Automation worked fine with iOS5 simulator, but not with iOS6 and iOS7

Tags: iphone, automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

It seems like iOS5 simulator is not supported on Mavericks. That was the only simulator that worked for me, and I have a bunch of tests in UI Automation. iOS6 and iOS7 simulator takes 2-5 times longer to load (about 30-50 seconds), and my guess is that instruments times out before the sim is started. I get a "An error occurred while trying to run the script." however - the error message appears after 1 minute. I have a MacBook Air 1.4 Ghz with 2GB of memory. Quite strange that iOS5 worked so snappy and all other simualtors so incredibly slow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a Mavericks issue. Are you using Xcode 5.0.1? I am and it completely broke the UIAutomation tool. I cannot run any tests at all as they all fail to start. I've tried Mountain Lion and Mavericks and the results are the same.

I hope Apple fixes this ASAP.

Comment: Same here. Completely down.

Comment: I sent a support request. Bug confirmed by Apple in 5.0.1

Comment: I'm running 5.0.2 and have the same problem.